# Yesod: Getting a database entity by ID from an Int

Tags: haskell, persistence, yesod

I'm new to both Haskell and Yesod, and am trying to build a simple web application that can answer queries from an external API. I have built a parser (using Parsec), that gets me the ID of an entity I want to load as a regular Int value.

However, I for the life of me can't figure out how to turn this Int into something that `get` will accept (i. e. a `Key` (?)). All the examples in the documentation only get the id from previous inserts, or from url dispatch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I seem to be stuck... :)

Comment: Okay, I figured this out thanks to the nice people on #yesod: 
To create a key from an Int, `i`, (or Int64, in this case) and for a database backend, the syntax is `Key $ PersistInt64 i`. This will create the key, and the compiler will figure out which entity to fetch from the context (i.e. type information associated with the use of the key).

Comment: Feel free to respond to your own question so that it is closed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Even if the answer can already be found in the comments, I would like to give a complete example.

Assuming we have a `Person` Model, the following function returns a record for the persion with the given ID (if it exists):

```
import Database.Persist.Types (PersistValue(PersistInt64))

getByIntId :: Integral i => i -> Handler (Maybe Person)
getByIntId i = runDB $ get $ Key $ PersistInt64 (fromIntegral i)
```

The `import` is needed to let us construct the persist-version of an integer. `fromIntegral` converts any integer to the expected type `Int64`.

**Update**: Since Yesod 1.2 `PersistValue` lives in the module `Database.Persist.Types`, before 1.2 it was `Database.Persist.Store` ([API Documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.3.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:PersistValue)).

**Update 2**: Since Persistent 2.0.2 there are two build-in functions to convert from/to database keys: `toSqlKey` and `fromSqlKey` ([API Documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.0.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#t:IsSqlKey), see [answer by hhefesto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781228) for an example).

Comment: Sven, I just wanted to let you know that you are doing folks like myself a huge favor by updating this post and increasing the "googleability" for Yesod / Haskel. Your answer saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Thank you! Always nice to hear (and motivating) that I can help people :)

Answer (score 5):

`PersistInt64` is here: `Database.Persist.Types`.

Previously `PersistInt64` was here: `Database.Persist.Store`.

Answer (score 3):

Just an example of how to use toSqlKey (Persistent 2.0.2)

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Users
    email String
    password String
    alias String
    deriving Show
|]

connStr = "host=localhost dbname=communis_db user=communis password=develpass port=5432"

inBackend :: ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) a-> IO a
inBackend action = runStderrLoggingT $ withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
  flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    action

toUserId :: Int64 -> UsersId
toUserId = toSqlKey

get_user :: Int64 -> IO (Maybe Users)
get_user = inBackend . get . toUserId

delete_user :: Int64 -> IO ()
delete_user = inBackend . delete . toUserId
```