# Fetch a Persistent record given its integral key?

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I'm trying to use Persistent with Servant, so I don't have the luxury of automatically parsing URL segments into Persistent keys. Instead, I've set up my routes to require an `Int64`, and I want to retrieve a record using that to perform primary key lookup.

[Everything I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8639414/465378) [points to using `toSqlKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28068447/465378) to convert an integer to a key, so I tried to write a very simple function that would do that for me:

```
runDB :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m) => (SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m))) a -> m a
runDB actions = do
  filename <- liftIO $ getEnv "SQLITE_FILENAME"
  runSqlite (pack filename) actions

getRecordByKey :: Int64 -> IO (Maybe (Entity Record))
getRecordByKey recordId = runDB $ get (toSqlKey recordId)
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work; I got the following type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘PersistEntityBackend
                                (Entity Record)’
            with actual type ‘SqlBackend’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘get (toSqlKey recordId)’
In the expression: runDB $ get (toSqlKey recordId)
In an equation for ‘getRecordByKey’:
    getRecordByKey recordId = runDB $ get (toSqlKey recordId)
```

I *sort of* understand this error—I looked up the types for `get` and `toSqlKey`, and they include the relevant constraints:

```
get :: (MonadIO m, backend ~ PersistEntityBackend val, PersistEntity val) => Key val -> ReaderT backend m (Maybe val)
toSqlKey :: ToBackendKey SqlBackend record => Int64 -> Key record
```

If I understand correctly, `backend` and `PersistEntityBackend val` need to be the same type, but `toSqlKey` enforces the `SqlBackend` constraint, so the types mismatch. My intuition tells me that `PersistentEntityBackend (Entity Record)` *should be* `SqlBackend`, but evidently I'm wrong there. I don't know why or how, though.

Anyway, I don't know if I'm right or wrong in that analysis, but either way, I'm not sure how to fix this or what the proper way of doing this is. How can/should I be getting a record from my database given an integer?

Comment: it's one of these things that's hard from afar - but I don't think you need the `liftIO $ return row` at all - just `runDB $ get (toSqlKey recordId)` should be enough

Comment: @Carsten Ah! You're quite right about that second point—I was doing more before I stripped it down in an attempt to debug the issue. As for the code, I think this is pretty much everything that's relevant, given that it doesn't actually depend on any aspect of my model. Let me know if you need more context, but I was able to drop this into an isolated sandbox and reproduce the error pretty trivially.

Comment: would you mind trying something (it would take me some time to get everything into a sandbox): change `runDB` to just `SqlPersistT IO a -> IO a` and remove the type-signature from `recordByKey` because I am really sure that this should work and it's most likely some of the nasty type stuff in there with the monad-transformers

Comment: did you try ``toPersistKey`` from ``Database.Persist.Base``?

Comment: @JanGreve `Database.Persist.Base` doesn't seem to exist in any remotely recent version of persist...?

Comment: @Carsten I can't easily do that because `runSqlite` includes those monad transformers, so I don't really have control over that type.

Comment: @AlexisKing, oops. My bad. Sorry. Google had some deep link into a old haddock.

Comment: To test @Carstens hinch, could you remove the type signature and test if the inferencer can figure it out and if there is something wrong?

Comment: @JanGreve yep that was the idea - and yep it works (in my experience that's the best way to use persistent: don't give signatures and look afterwards)

Comment: @Carsten That is mine, too :) Glad to see not being alien with that approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me (may depend on the versions of your packages ... sadly):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Stackoverlflow where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Logger(NoLoggingT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control (MonadBaseControl)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (ResourceT)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import Data.Text (pack)
import Database.Persist.Class (ToBackendKey, get)
import Database.Persist.Sql (SqlBackend, SqlPersistT, toSqlKey)
import Database.Persist.Sqlite(runSqlite)
import Database.Persist.Types (Entity)
import System.Environment (getEnv)

runDB :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m) =>
        (SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m))) a -> m a
runDB actions = do
  filename <- liftIO $ getEnv "SQLITE_FILENAME"
  runSqlite (pack filename) actions

getRecordByKey :: (MonadIO m, ToBackendKey SqlBackend val, MonadBaseControl IO m) =>
                 Int64 -> m (Maybe val)
getRecordByKey recordId = runDB $ get (toSqlKey recordId)
```

as you can see I just added alot of types annotations (well GHC did after I removed the signatures and ask it to tell me ;))

also note that I don't have your `Record` so you should easily be able to get rid of the `... val` stuff!

Comment: Ah, I see, we have the same approach to complex type definitions;)

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it... and probably the better way. As a result of this, though, I think I found out what the original problem was: `get` doesn't return a `Maybe (Entity Record)`, it returns a `Maybe Record`. After all that, *that* was the problem. Even with that knowledge, the error message is still incomprehensible, but hey, so it goes. :P

Comment: Ohh, I see it now. The issue was that `PersistEntityBackend (Entity Record)` doesn't exist, but `PersistEntityBackend Record` does, and it is a `SqlBackend`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem: happens to me all the time - don't judge me but for persistent and co. I let ghc-mod/emacs write the signatures (it's much smarter than me ^^)

Answer (score 1):

And what about making `Key record` directly an instance of `FromText`/`ToText` and use the keys in the URL directly?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances               #-}
instance ToBackendKey SqlBackend record => FromText (Key record) where
  fromText k = toSqlKey <$> fromText k
instance ToBackendKey SqlBackend record => ToText (Key record) where
  toText = toText . fromSqlKey
```